# respond_with location ignored on GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

At each step in my checkout process, an order is updated via a `PUT` request.  However, one of the states has a form that submits to a third party which redirects back to my site, calling the update method with `GET` (no control over this).

Why does my `respond_with` code appear to be totally ignored and I get a `Missing Template checkout/update` error?  It should be hitting `#edit`.

**CheckoutController.rb**

```
before_filter :load_order

def update
  if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
    @order.next
  end
  respond_with(@order, :location => checkout_state_url(@order.state))
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/checkout/update/:state' => 'checkout#update', :as => :update_checkout
match '/checkout/:state' => 'checkout#edit', :as => :checkout_state
match '/checkout' => 'checkout#edit', :state => 'client_details', :as => :checkout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `respond_with` does different things depending upon the HTTP verb and whether the resource has errors.  See [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/tag/http/) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html).

The following code worked for me:

```
def update
    if @order.update_attributes(params[:order]) && @order.next
        respond_with(@order) { |format| format.html { redirect_to checkout_state_url(@order.state) } }
    else
        respond_with(@order) { |format| format.html { render :edit } }
    end
end
```